# Creating Dynamic Object Keys After mapping on an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, jsx

So I want to create a quite complex data structure that looks like the following:

```
slots: {
    'slot_1': {
         id: 'slot_1',
         associatedCard: {}
         },
    'slot_2': {
         id: 'slot_2',
         associatedCard: {}
         },
    'slot_3': {
         id: 'slot_3',
         associatedCard: {}
         }
}
```

I have 10 slots that I want to populate with cards (each slot can contain one card) so I am actually looping over the cards, creating the slots and I tried to dynamically generate the above data structure. Here is my code:

```
 slots: (() => {
        return {
            ...cards.map((card, index) => {
            return {
                            [`slot_${index + 1}`]: {
                                id: `slot_${index + 1}`,
                                ownedCard: {}
                            }
                        };
                    })
                };
            })(),
```

However, I am not getting what I desire. This is what I get:
[image]

How can I fix this so that I have slot_1 instead of 0 as key, slot_2 instead of 1 as key, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the items, [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them, instead:

```js
cards.reduce((acc, card, index) => {
    return { ...acc,
            [`slot_${index + 1}`]: {
                id: `slot_${index + 1}`,
                ownedCard: {}
            }
        };
    }, {})
```

The `.map` method will produce an *array* of new items based on the old ones. And since you return an object, you get an array of objects. Yet, what you want is *one* object that has all those keys. The `.reduce` method is more advanced (as in, can do more stuff) and it turns an array into "one value" -> hence **reduce**. Your desired value is a single object, so you can just combine each of them.

An alternative to using the spread notation is to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and re-use the same object instead of doing a clone every time:

```js
cards.reduce((acc, card, index) => {
    return Object.assign{acc, {
            [`slot_${index + 1}`]: {
                id: `slot_${index + 1}`,
                ownedCard: {}
            }}
        };
    }, {});
```

If you do want to keep the `.map`, then you can still chain that into `.reduce`:

```js
cards.map((card, index) => {
    return {
            [`slot_${index + 1}`]: {
                id: `slot_${index + 1}`,
                ownedCard: {}
            }
        };
})
.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, ...obj}));
```

or

```js
cards.map((card, index) => {
    return {
            [`slot_${index + 1}`]: {
                id: `slot_${index + 1}`,
                ownedCard: {}
            }
        };
})
.reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, obj), {});
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that for all of these options except for the `Object.assign` versions, new objects are created in each iteration. I also wouldn't duplicate the id creation, or do it inline as it makes it much harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `map` returns an array, which is why you are getting numbered keys. You need to do something like:

```
const slots = cards.reduce((obj, card, index) => {
  const id = `slot_${index + 1}`
  obj[id] = {
    id,
    associatedCard: card
  }
  return obj
}, {})
```